# check_resid() function in itsadug package visualizing results of bam function in mgcv package returns error

Tags: r, time-series, gam, mgcv

I am going through the tutorial "Overview GAMM analysis of time series data" (http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~jvanrij/Tutorial/GAMM.html)

I fit a model with the following code:

```
m1 <- bam(Y ~ Group 
        + s(Time, by=Group) 
        + s(Condition, by=Group, k=5) 
        + ti(Time, Condition, by=Group)
        + s(Time, Subject, bs='fs', m=1)
        + s(Trial, Subject, bs='fs', m=1),
        data=simdat)
```

The I run the following command from the itsadug package:

```
check_resid(m1, split_pred=c("Subject", "Trial") )
```

This returns an exception:

```
Warning message in is.na(res.rho):
"is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'"
Error in ts(x): 'ts' object must have one or more observations
Traceback:

1. check_resid(m1, split_pred = c("Subject", "Trial"))
2. acf(res, main = sprintf("ACF resid(%s)", deparse(substitute(model))), 
 .     col = "darkgray", ylim = range(c(0, acf(res, plot = FALSE)$acf[, 
 .         , 1], acf(res.rho[!is.na(res.rho)], plot = FALSE)$acf[, 
 .         , 1]), na.rm = TRUE), bty = "L")
3. plot.acf(acf.out, ...)
4. acf(res.rho[!is.na(res.rho)], plot = FALSE)
5. na.action(as.ts(x))
6. as.ts(x)
7. as.ts.default(x)
8. ts(x)
9. stop("'ts' object must have one or more observations")
```

The first two plots only are produced (instead of 4).

I checked the documentation of the command and perhaps this is relevant:

> AR_start
>
> Defaults to NULL. Only use this when the model was run in an old
>   versions of package mgcv and the function cannot retrieve the used
>   AR.start values from the model. When an error is shown with newer
>   versions of mgcv, please check the column provided as values of
>   AR.start. when using old versions of package mgcv. Function will give
>   error when it cannot find AR.start.

How can I correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax (see the help `?check_resid`) is:

```
check_resid(m1, split_by=c("Subject", "Trial") )
```

and the output is:

[image]